# $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_URI'] is empty

Tags: php, apache, php-7.3

I migrated servers and now this variable `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_URI']` stopped working, what can I do?

I'm temporarily using this solution: `$uri_parts = explode('?', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 2)[0];` but there's a lot of code that uses `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_URI']` and I don't want to be changing all of that.

Comment: Show us the contents from before and from after

Comment: If you dont want to change "*all of that*", then just assign `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_URI']` at the top of your global include file to what you get from the uri split line of code. I've personally never used `DOCUMENT_URI`, in anything. Because it has never worked in any environment I've worked in.

Comment: @IncredibleHat I did think about that, but do you know the reason why it’s not working anymore? I did not setup the old server so I don’t what they did to make it work?

Comment: does both web servers have the same configurations?

Comment: 99% sure that your apache configuration is different

Comment: @Mazzy I'm 110% sure that that's the problem ;) , but I didn't copy everything to the new server, we wanted to start clean because the older one had problems. Anyways I followed IncredibleHats suggestion, which took some time, but fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DOCUMENT_URI` is not a standard variable as far as I can tell. Whatever, there're two things to note about the [`$_SERVER` superglobal](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php):

- It isn't read-only.
- It populates from several sources, including environment variables.

You can just set an environment variable by whatever mean you prefer (for instance, the [`SetEnv` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_env.html#setenv) if you happen to use Apache) or simply put your own value right into the PHP variable.